# Merge data from two tables horizontally

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, query-optimization

I have data coming from two source table "T" & "S" as below
[image]

I want to merge the data horizontally from two tables and show the result as below
[image]

Column name in Result are fixed where

- D1,D2,D3 are date column that shows last 3 max(TDATE) after merging data from table T & S for each group "Code"
- TID1,TID2,TID3 are ID
  from table T for Date D1,D2,D3
- SID1,SID2,SID3 are ID from table S for
  Date D1,D2,D3

My below query is returning result

```
WITH L1 AS
(
SELECT NULL AS TID, SID, CODE, TDATE 
FROM (VALUES
('S1','A','2001-01-01'),
('S3','A','2001-01-03'),
('S5','B','2001-01-05')
) V(SID,CODE,TDATE)
UNION ALL
SELECT TID, NULL AS SID, CODE, TDATE 
FROM (VALUES

('T1','A','2001-01-01'),
('T2','A','2001-01-02'),
('T5','B','2001-01-05')
) V(TID,CODE,TDATE)
)
,L2 AS 
(
SELECT SID,TID,CODE,[TDATE],
DENSE_RANK () over (
         partition by CODE
         order by [TDATE] desc
       ) RNO
FROM L1
)
,L3 AS 
(
SELECT MAX(TID) AS TID,MAX(SID) AS SID,CODE,TDATE,MAX(RNO)AS RNO
FROM L2
GROUP BY CODE,TDATE,RNO
HAVING MAX(RNO)<=3
)
SELECT * FROM L3
```

[image]

Now if I replace the last line of the query "Select * from L3" with the below query that pivot the result horizontally I am getting the correct result.

```
SELECT 
 R1.CODE
 ,R1.TID AS TID1,R2.TID AS TID2,R3.TID AS TID3
 ,R1.SID AS SID1,R2.SID AS SID2,R3.SID AS SID3
 ,R1.TDATE AS D1 , R2.TDATE AS D2 , R3.TDATE AS D3 
FROM L3 R1
LEFT OUTER JOIN L3 R2 ON R1.RNO+1=R2.RNO AND R1.CODE=R2.CODE
LEFT OUTER JOIN L3 R3 ON R1.RNO+2=R3.RNO AND R1.CODE=R3.CODE
where R1.RNO=1
```

The problem is the above query is very slow when I have to run it with thousands of record in Table T & S with the last 5 dates in column D1,D2,D3,D4,D5

Is there any other way to optimise this query or a new query that can run fast?

I tried to add indexes on table T & S as below

- The primary Key On T(TID) & S(SID)
- Index on T(Code,TDATE)
- Index on T(TDATE)
- Index on S(Code,TDATE)
- Index on S(TDATE)

Total rows in Table T & S are approx 50K each and the query is still running after 6 mins

Here is a link for an execution plan for the actual query that is very slow
[Execution Plan of actual slow query](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJX8W7BNO)

Comment: The _actual execution plan_ is a good place to look for performance information. Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a way to include an execution plan in your question.

Comment: Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info) then [edit] your question to give us a bit more information so we can help you.

Comment: Thanks, @HOBO I have included a link for the execution plan for the actual query that is running slow.

Comment: Hi  @O. Jones I have updated the Question and link for the execution plan after adding indexes to all tables in query

Comment: Try changing the indexes on the source tables (`T` and `S`) from `( Code, TDate )` to `( Code, TDate desc )` to match the needs of your `Dense_Rank`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are killing performance by doing the joins in your last select.

What about trying a pivot operation instead? Replace the select with:

```
SELECT
    CODE
   ,Max(IIF(rno = 1, TID, NULL)) Tid1
   ,Max(IIF(rno = 2, TID, NULL)) Tid2
   ,Max(IIF(rno = 3, TID, NULL)) Tid3
   ,Max(IIF(rno = 1, SID, NULL)) Sid1
   ,Max(IIF(rno = 2, SID, NULL)) Sid2
   ,Max(IIF(rno = 3, SID, NULL)) Sid3
   ,Max(IIF(rno = 1, Tdate, NULL)) D1
   ,Max(IIF(rno = 2, Tdate, NULL)) D2
   ,Max(IIF(rno = 3, Tdate, NULL)) D3
FROM L3
GROUP BY Code
```